# upload a .mp4 video using the REST API (VoD) to ant media server

Tags: ant-media-server-sdk

when uploading my video,I get the following error message: `{"success": false, "message": "notMp4File", "dataId": null, "errorId": 0}`
except here is my file; it's in .mp4 extension: `1- Introduction---.mp4 (type: "video/mp4"; size: 1255840 bytes)`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this problem and I will leave this answer in case someone comes across this mistake:
in my example, the name of our video will be `zoom_1.mp4`

```
http://localhost:5080/LiveApp/rest/v2/vods/create?name=zoom_1.mp4
```

where `zoom_1.mp4` is the name of my video
in the form, I pass a field of type file `(accept="video/*")`
[image]